# How to login into mysql shell from localhost instead of '%'?

Tags: mysql-5.5

I need to grant a permission to a newly created user. I have access to root. But, i can't grant a permission to a new user. When I run:

```
grant all privileges on 'newuser'.* to 'newuser'@localhost;
```

I got this:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'newuser'
```

The part that I don't understand is why do I logged in as `'root'@'%'`? Since I logged in with this command:

```
mysql --protocol TCP -h localhost -u root -p
```

But this:

```
select user(), current_user();
```

gives me this:

```
+----------+----------------+
| user()   | current_user() |
+----------+----------------+
| root@::1 | root@%         |
+----------+----------------+
```

I know only `'root'@'localhost'` has grant privilege. Then I check `mysql.user` table which gives me output (only different columns shown here):

```
+-----------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
| Host      | User    | Grant_priv | authentication_string |
+-----------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
| localhost | root    | Y          |                       |
| %         | root    | N          | NULL                  |
+-----------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Other columns that is not included above for `'root'@'localhost'` and `'root'@'%'` are identical.

So, back to my question: How to login into mysql shell from localhost instead of '%'?

**NOTE**: I run mysql version 5.5.21 on windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

`user()` function shows what have your client answered when server asks "Who are you?".

Query shows that your client answers using IPv6 local address.

There is no such record in your `mysql.user` table. But server finds the record which client's information is matched to. `current_user()` function shows what account was applied by server for the authentication based on the client's info.

Simply tell your client that it must connect to server using IPv4 - in command line or in configuration file, or disable IPv6 somewhere - on the client, or on the server, or on the workstation. Or add one more user with grant privileges - `'root'@'::1'` (recommended).

I don't know why your server cannot convert `'::1'` adddress to `'localhost'` name. Maybe you have no proper record `::1 localhost` in your HOSTS file?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how is your HOSTS file is built.
Typing `localhost` may resolve into `::1` rather than `127.0.0.1`

You could simply try to type `127.0.0.1` as the hostname.

```bash
mysql --protocol TCP -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```